# Can errors showing up when building a CSV reader in NetBeans be ignored?

Tags: csv, netbeans

For my study I'm following a course that includes a bit of programming. The project we are working on now includes building a CSV reader in NetBeans. The reader I've build seems to be working despite it showing me an error. Because I'm new in programming I wondered if I can just ignore the error or will it work better/differently when it's fixed?

Comment: A question like this, including the relevant code that's causing the error, may be a better fit for Stack Overflow. I imagine a good answer will depend on the error, right?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Stack Overflow, a site much like this, exists specifically for questions related to programming, and I've requested your question be migrated there. Also, the question as asked is nigh useless; to make it useful, edit it to identify the package you're trying to build and to include the messages which provoke your concern.

Comment: Look into Exception handling, and post over at stack overflow. no, you should not be getter errors if everything is working right, but you can handle (or ignore) errors related to errors in the documents formatting, but more likely your error is coming from bad handling of the input file. files have to be handled carefully, and closed when done.

Comment: And what **is** the error that is shown?